# Eclipse could not find gradle repository

Tags: eclipse, adt, android-gradle-plugin, eclipse-adt, gradle-eclipse

I try to install gradle plug-in for Eclipse but it could not find gradle repository.
What could be the problem?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Really hard to say. Could be a temporary problem with the repository, or it could be problem with your internet connection, or it could be a problem with proxy/firewall configuration of your eclipse. If you are in network environment that is behind a proxy/firewall this is the most likely problem.

Comment: I get this error when I use Eclipse ADT, but when I use another Eclipse everything ok

Comment: Finally I found a solution, I closed my antivirus then Eclipse successfully find gradle repository.